# Extract Closed captions from dvb-t

Tags: linux, media, video-capture, closed-captions

I want to be able to get the closed captions from a stream on a dvb-t card on my linux machine.

From what I can tell when I use mythtv to view the card it can see the captions and display them on screen. But I would like to have a script running that gathers the captions and places them in a txt file.

Card: Winfast DTV1000S / DTV3200

Comment: To which programming language are you interested?

Comment: Any language that can do it. I just need to get to the end result of having the captions in a textfile

Comment: You might want to look at `vbiutil` to get started - it analyses an MPEG stream to extract the subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

The MythTV wiki gives a script which does this:
http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Closed_captioning#Extracting_closed_captions_to_a_.srt_file

It uses the open source tool "CCextractor" to do it.

This will work for US closed captions (not European format subtitles) but assuming that was OK for you it might work with no programming at all.

CCextractor is also open source, so if want to add support for European standard subtitles, well, I'm sure the developers of CCextractor wouldn't object

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work with AU broadcasting. I have already been in contact with the ccextracter developer and he has stated that it would not work as the AU uses bitmaps as closed captions as far as he can tell which would requier ocring. But thanks for the reply

Comment: ah, oz .. I should have guessed :-) Bitmaps would be an issue alright. I have quite some experience with OCR and it is highly non-trivial.

Comment: I would think that any decent OCR toolkit would handle subtitles without much problem at all... They are in a standard size and standard font, if you can extract the bitmaps: http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/ Anyway, are you sure that the subtitles aren't embedded in the stream. It think that's the case here in Sweden.